# What does the saying CON VALOR mean?

Tags: traducción, significado

What does the saying CON VALOR mean?

I am translating a title of a report and the client wants to emphasize corporate core values:
el título refiere a Valor económico, Valor de valores corporativos, Valor coraje, tiene varios significados, se hizo así adrede.

Comment: To me is unclear what you are asking. I think that you should rewrite this question to be more clear. You are right `valor` stands for _value_ (economic or corporative values) and _bravery/courage_. What is exactly the question?

Comment: I would translate this as "With Courage."  True, this doesn't get at all the meanings, but it pulls out the most important one.

Answer (score 1):

It literally means "with value" but the "valores" you're writing about aren't value of the monetary kind but values as in principles, like family values.

Comment: I understand the literal meaning of Con Valor, With Value.
I am asking about the saying,used sometimes as call to action or as a rallying cry to inspire a sports team or a group of people.

Comment: In that context then it's about bravery like Diego mentioned. Something like "let's be brave"

Answer (score 1):

***Valor*** can refer to **monetary value** for example: **"Este automovil no tiene *valor*"**  is like saying *This car has no monetary value.*

Also, ***Valor*** may refer to **courage** for example **"Tuve el *valor* de matarlos"** meaning  *I had the courage to kill them.*

Comment: Bienvenido! gracias por tu aportación.. evita usar MAYÚSCULAS, aprovecha las **negritas**, *italicas* y ***negritas italicas*** con [markdown](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) para resaltar tus respuestas y hacerlas más legibles.

Answer (score 0):

con valor means "with values". That value can be economical or humanistic.

Answer (score 0):

"[Con](http://dle.rae.es/con) [Valor](http://dle.rae.es/valor)" has many different meaning depending of the context. In fact, the word "Valor" has 11 different meanings, and the word "con" has six different meanings. However, the ones that applies here are:

- Principle. E.g. "Con valores familiares como esos, tu puedes..."
- Valor/Bravery/Courage. E.g. "Con valor podremos enfrentar al enemigo..."
- Monetary. E.g. "Con el valor de ese equipo, podriamos comprar..."
- Mathematics. E.g "Con valor equitativo al de la 'y' "

If you want a more complete answer, I suggest to consult the dictionary of the Royal Spanish Academy. *"The Real Academia Española (English: Royal Spanish Academy), generally abbreviated as RAE, is the official royal institution responsible for overseeing the Spanish language..."* - Wikipedia